# Creating 100+ folders and naming them sequentially

Tags: python, directory

I'm trying to create 143 folders using the os.makedirs() tool, but I'm having some trouble. I can only generate one folder at a time, and I'd like to make all of them at once. I would like the folders to be named IMG_0016 through IMG_00160.

I thought of trying a for loop with a counter, where each loop would add the new number to the end of the folder title, but I can't get it to work.

```
import os

for folders in range(0, 143):
    count = 0016

    os.makedirs("C:\\Users\joshuarb\Desktop\Organized_Images\IMG"+count)

    count = count+1
```

Comment: You've got a few good answers already, but as a recommendation if you do not need the two leading zeros, why not try the numbering to be IMG_0016 to IMG_0160. This would help if you ever need to sort them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easier and more readable to use the direct numbers (note that you want to use 161 in the `range()` call, since the last number is not included):

```
import os

for count in range (16, 161):
    os.makedirs("C:\\Users\joshuarb\Desktop\Organized_Images\IMG_{:04d}".format(count))
```

Also notice that I used a zero-padding with width 4, since your naming convention differs for IMG_0016 and IMG_00160 so I chose to limit to DOS' usual 8-character. Adjust according to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You are redeclaring `count = 0016` every loop iteration. Put this outside the loop.

```
import os

count = 0016

for folders in range (0, 143):

    os.makedirs("C:\\Users\joshuarb\Desktop\Organized_Images
    IMG"+count)

    count = count+1
```

Comment: It fixes the primary problem with the code. I'm aware that his code isn't exactly "good", but it's not my job to fix it for him when it falls outside the scope of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for this kind of task there is no neccessity to use temporary variable. Use may and should use variable which iterates over range.

Secondly, `range` creates range from 0 by default, so you may drop the left interval boundary. For your specific task, the best way is to iterate over required interval: from 16 to 160.

Thirdly, in Windows it is better to use raw-string to store path or mask every backslash, because single backslash is recognized as start of meta-symbol.

And the latest thing, it is recommended to use `format` while joining strings.

So, the final solution may look like this:

```
import os
base_path = "C:\\Users\\joshuarb\\Desktop\\Organized_Images\\"
dir_basename = "IMG_00"
for index in range(16, 161):
    os.makedirs("{}{}{}".format(base_path, dir_basename, index))
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop manually keeping track of `count` and use the results of `range`:

```
first_num = 16
folder_count = 143
base_path = r"C:\Users\joshuarb\Desktop\Organized_Images"

for folder_num in range(first_num, first_num + folder_count):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(base_path, "IMG"+str(folder_num).zfill(4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

for folders in range(1,5):

    os.makedirs(os.getcwd()+'/folder00'+ str(folders))
```

use `os.getcwd()` if the target at same directory else give some path